# What we can do vs What can we do

Tags: sentence

Are **"What we can do"** and **"What can we do"** both correct and if yes, is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe both are correct for different circumstances.

If you are leading a conversation with a group of people but don't know how to overcome (or approach) the current topic, you may ask **"What can we do?"** This would effectively try to solicit responses from the group.

Person: "We need to raise funds to buy more school supplies."
You: "What can we do to have a successful fundraiser?"

In a similar situation, you may actually know the actions the group can take. Since you have a suggestion, you can say **"What we can do..."** to propose your idea.

Person: "We need to raise funds to buy more school supplies."
You: "What we can do is have a car wash!"

Comment: Great answer. Probably quicker to say one is a question, one is not.